# How to fix Firestore query suddenly not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing google cloud api function and the following query did work(means get the data) when I made first.
`query = db.collection(collectionId).where('dataSchema', '==', 'messages').order_by('dataSourceModifyDate', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(1)`

But I was developing other query and re-run the query, but it didn't work(means didn't get any data) although that query works in the google cloud platform.

```
query = db.collection(collectionId).where('dataSchema', '==', 'messages').order_by('dataSourceModifyDate', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(1)
     docs = query.get()
     temp = datetime.datetime.strptime('1900-01-01T00:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
     if len(list(docs)) != 0:
         recent_doc = list(docs)[0]
                temp = datetimewithnanoToDatetime(recent_doc.to_dict()['dataSourceModifyDate'])
```

If run code, the following error occurs.

```
File "D:\work\upwork\simon_chapleau\projects\krakenGetEntitiesFrom365.py", line 210, in index
return getEntitiesFrom365(request)
File "D:\work\upwork\simon_chapleau\projects\krakenGetEntitiesFrom365.py", line 97, in getEntitiesFrom365
recent_doc = list(docs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because get is returning iterator, and you are calling the iterator (`docs`) twice. I am not sure how to explain it fast so look at this console screenshot:

[image]

First part I call iterator len it has value, but next time it does not.

So when you check it in `if len(list(docs)) != 0:` you get value and next time you call the same - it do not have. I think the solution will be to create the list and work with it (like in list_it2 in the example).

Comment: Wow, you're a genius. Thanks very much. I've wasted too much time to solve this problem and I gonna crazy.
At last, I've post question here as a last resort. Your answer is perfect.